# f(int x) { return x == 0 ? 0 : 1; } in Java without conditionals

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I want to implement `f(int x) { return x == 0 ? 0 : 1; }` in Java.

In C, I'd just "`return !!x;`", but `!` doesn't work like that in Java. Is there some way to do it without conditionals? Without something cheesy like an unrolled version of

```
int ret = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
    ret |= ((x & (1 << i)) >>> i);
}
```

or

```
try {
   return x/x;
} catch (ArithmeticException e) {
   return 0;
}
```

)

**EDIT:**

So, I did a microbenchmark of three different solutions:

1. my return x/x catch solution,
2. the obvious x==0?0:1 solution, and
3. Ed Staub's solution: (x|-x) >>> 31.

The timings for random int inputs (the whole int range) were:

```
1. 0.268716  
2. 0.324449  
3. 0.347852
```

Yes, my stupid x/x solution was faster by a pretty hefty margin. Not very surprising when you consider that there are very few 0's in it, and in the vast majority of cases the fast path is taken.

The timings for the more interesting case where 50% of inputs are 0:

```
1. 1.256533  
2. 0.321485  
3. 0.348999
```

The naive `x==0?0:1` solution was faster by about 5% than the clever one (on my machine). I'll try to do some disassembly tomorrow to find out why.

**EDIT2:**
Ok, so the disassembly for the conditional version is (excluding book-keeping):

```
testl rsi,rsi
setnz rax
movzbl rax,rax
```

The disassembly for (x|-x)>>>31 is:

```
movl rax,rsi
negl rax
orl rax,rsi
sarl rax,#31
```

I don't think anything else needs to be said.

Comment: didn't understand the question sorry

Comment: ...tricky question, but a good one...

Comment: Why do you want to avoid a simple conditional expression?

Comment: What does the `f(int x)` return for a given input?   @Jim: I'm assuming it's a self imposed challenge.

Comment: Can I use this : `return BooleanUtils.toInteger( a == 0 , 0 , 1)` ??

Comment: @Jim Garrison, avoiding branching could be considered to be more multi-processor/multi-gpu friendly. Who knows what kind of toaster he's going to run the code on.

Comment: @Crom, so what *is* the motivation for this?

Comment: @Dilum Ranatunga, @Alexander, @Jim Garrison: no toaster :) - it's just for fun.

Comment: I imagine the `x==0?0:1` solution is actually compiled into something fast by the compiler, which is why it's faster. It can't figure out that you're trying to be clever with `(i|-i)>>>31` so you don't get the super-performant version.

Comment: @Orion Adrian: yep - See Edit2.

Comment: When I see stuff like this I ask what is the consumer of f() really trying to do?  Asking out of context a question like this doesn't make for better software.  It makes for short terse clever code.  Remember code is for humans to read, not for computers to store compactly/run fast.

Comment: Exception is a branch. Conditional operation, well, branch there too. Only Ed's solution is correct. This type of stuff is important if you do this for crypto, where you must never have branches to prevent timing attacks.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Ok, shortest solution without conditional is probably:

```
return (i|-i) >>> 31;
```

Comment: Is Java never going to change the size of int so that 31 would eventually be incorrect?

Comment: @Orion how about `return (i|-i) >>> java.math.BigInteger.valueOf(Integer.MAX_VALUE).bitLength();`

Comment: @eng.Fouad, talk about taking a quick solution and trashing it with no fewer than 2 function calls.

Comment: If you really want to get rid of the majick 31, the right way is return `(i|-i) >>> (Integer.SIZE-1);`.  I certainly wouldn't do it out of forward-compatibility concerns, though - only to make it clear where the 31 came from.  There is far, far too much code that would break for them to ever change the size of an int.

Comment: yay 30+ up repution till now ;)

Comment: @Eng.Fouad - Who would have thought a dozen characters would be worth 300+ rep?

Comment: @Ed Staub: It's not the dozen characters. It's knowing what to do with them.

Answer (score 11):

Here is a solution:

```
public static int compute(int i)
{
    return ((i | (~i + 1)) >> 31) & 1; // return ((i | -i) >> 31) & 1
}
```

**EDIT:**

or you can make it more simple:

```
public static int compute(int i)
{
    return -(-i >> 31); // return -i >>> 31
}
```

**EDIT2:**

last solution fails with negative numbers. Take a look at @Ed Staub's solution.

**EDIT3:**

@Orion Adrian OK, here is a general solution:

```
public static int compute(int i)
{
    return (i|-i) >>> java.math.BigInteger.valueOf(Integer.MAX_VALUE).bitLength();
}
```

Comment: @Eng.Fouad: Nice! I could feel this would be done with | and ~, but I couldn't quite think of it myself. Although, if you replace (~i + 1) with -i, it would be a bit better.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad: Your revised version doesn't work. compute(1) would return -1, for example. The best answer is probably (1|-1)>>>31, pointed out by Ed.

Comment: @CromTheDestroyer `compute(1)` would return `1` and you're right .. @Ed Staub's solution is much better

Comment: See, i *knew* there was something you could involving bits!

Comment: No concern about when int = 64 bits in the future?

Comment: @Orion Adrian: When would that happen? With Java's backwards compatibility, I doubt they'd change the bit length of an int. They'd probably just add a new type `superlong` for 128 bit numbers.

Comment: @Bart van Heukelom, I agree with you, but then again, C++ went through that hell as well when people didn't think they would change it. Though I'd probably put the `java.math.Big...` in a constant for performance reasons.

Answer (score 8):

```
int f(int x) {
    return Math.abs(Integer.signum(x));
}
```

The `signum()` function returns the sign of the number as -1, 0 or 1. So all what's left is to turn -1 into 1, which is what `abs` does.

Comment: _If_ the objection to a conditional was based on performance concerns, surely this cure is worse than the disease.

Comment: @Ed, I for one did not see any mention of performance in the original question. Indeed, the divide and catch example gave me the impression of some entirely different motivation.

Comment: This is kinda cheating since Math.abs has a conditional internally : p

Comment: int f(int x) {Integer.signum(x) & 1;} would be a little bit-twiddlier.

Comment: I wonder why people upvote this.... `Math.abs(i)` does `return (a < 0) ? -a : a;` internally... isn't that what the question is trying to avoid?

Comment: @Dilum - nor did I - hence the italics on "_If_".  I'm clueless as to the motivation.

Answer (score 7):

The `signum` function implements it this way

```
return (i >> 31) | (-i >>> 31);
```

so, just add another bitwise operation to return `0` or `1`

```
return ((i >> 31) | (-i >>> 31)) & 1;
```

Answer (score 7):

All of these solutions seem to suffer from the vice of taking varying degrees of effort to understand.  That means the programmer who must later read and maintain this code will have to expend unnecessary effort.  That costs money.

The expression

```
(x == 0)? 0:1
```

is straightforward and  simple to understand.   It's really the right way to do this.  The use of an exception in the ordinary run of code is downright ghastly.   Exceptions are for handling circumstances beyond programmer control, not for ordinary routine operations.

Comment: Totally correct, except where very extreme performance requirements pertain, as in image processing.  In that case, using the solution I suggested in a "final" method should eliminate any branching that might cause a pipeline stall.   But I think this was meant mostly as a puzzle.

Comment: @Ed, on the right hardware with the right hotspot, the conditional can evaluate faster than the two operation bit math. Also, on hardware that does pay for the conditional, the `? 0 : 1` expression is a relatively easy expression to optimize at the compiler/hotspot level, right?

Comment: @Dilum, of course there's theoretically hardware where your mileage may differ.  And if hotspot recognized the entire expression, it might JIT-compile it down to a single instruction on some theoretical machine that had such an instruction.  But on most machines, the expression `(i|-i) >>> 31` should JIT-compile it down, with no optimization at all, down to 3 instructions (negate, or, shift), with no memory accesses beyond the initial load and final store, with no branches, on nearly all machines.  That's pretty hard to beat.  cont...

Comment: The best I'd expect with branching, on most machines, would be 4 - negate, or, branch-if-0 (with potential stall), and load.  Add another fraction if the compiler isn't willing to use two return statements.

Comment: @ncmathsadist: Eh - does no one read tags? I clearly marked this "code-kata" just to avoid this sort of answer. @Ed Staub is right - it's just a puzzle. Also, why are you mentioning my implementation with the exception? I clearly stated that was an example of what I *didn't* want.

Comment: @Ed, there are instruction sets that do conditional evaluation without branching, for example in ARM.

Comment: @Dilum, ah, thanks much, very cool, [I see](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture#Conditional_execution).  The JIT might well be smart enough to recognize that the two zeros are the same value in `(x == 0)? 0:1` - this is a fairly common case.  If so, would this really be just one instruction - "load 1 if non-zero"?

Answer (score 1):

I wonder what the compiler would turn this into...

```
class kata {

    public static int f(int x){
     return -(Boolean.valueOf(x==0).compareTo(true));
    }

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         System.out.println(f(0));
         System.out.println(f(5));
         System.out.println(f(-1));

     }
}
```

http://ideone.com/ssAVo

Answer (score 0):

This question reduces down to: "Is there a way to map boolean true,false to int 1,0 respectively without writing the conditional."

In Java, there is no standardized treatment of `true` as `1`. The closest is use of `-1`. So as @Ed says, the ternary operator is as succinct as you get.

Comment: He was asking for fast, not succint.

Comment: If you read my question, you'll see I wasn't asking for fast, nor succinct. I was just asking for a bit-twiddly way of eliminating the conditional, since I find this sort of thing fun.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted a boolean,  i think:

```
return x == x >>> 1
```

Would do it, because the only number whose set bits don't move when shifted is one with no set bits.

Under the hood, the bytecode actually uses 1 and 0 for true and false, but i don't know of any way to turn a Java language boolean value into its corresponding int value without some sort of conditional.

Comment: If he wanted a boolean, he could have written `return x == 0`.

Comment: Yeah. I had some sort of idea bouncing around in my head about bit patterns, but by the time it came out it was nonsense. I'm going to leave this answer undeleted in case anyone needs a laugh.

Comment: @Rotsor: No, because that's a logical shift right, not an arithmetic shift right. It works. It's pointless, but it works.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I thought it was a circular shift right (`ROR`). I'm deleting my comment.